# How to compare different categoricals in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to compare categoricals with slightly different values

```
cats1=pd.Categorical(["a", "b"])
cats2=pd.Categorical(["c", "b"])
cats1==cats2
```

This will throw an error because their value set in not identical. They come  from different data sources, but the values are mostly the same.

Can I compare them efficiently without converting the whole columns to a string?

I need the boolean vector that you would get if the above comparison worked.

Comment: `cats1.isin(cats2)`

Comment: do you want `cats1.isin(cats2).any()` ?

Comment: Rather the full boolean vector.

Comment: This is a guess `pd.factorize(cats1)[0] == pd.factorize(cats2)[0]`

Comment: I doubt `factorize` will create the same numbers for equal categories.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out already, you can use `x.isin(y)` to see what of `x` can be found in `y`. To see exactly how much they overlap, you can do this:

```
res = cats1.isin(cats2)
print(res.mean())
```

Output:

```
0.5
```